# Seam navigation rule to prevent access to any application url from particular page (after user log in)

Tags: jsf, seam2

Is there a way to prevent user accessing ANY page of application directly from particular page after log in using only JSF/Seam 2 navigation rules in pages.xml.

The aim - is to force user change password if it is expired. I considered something like following snippet ("user" - is a Seam `@Name` bean):

```
<page view-id="/editUserPwd.xhtml">
    <navigation>
        <rule if="#{user.changeRequestedToUser}">
            <redirect view-id="/editUserPwd.xhtml"/>
        </rule>
    </navigation>
</page>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it...

```
<page view-id="*">
    <navigation>
        <rule if="#{identity.isLoggedIn() and user.passwordExpiredFlag}">
            <redirect view-id="/editUserPwd.xhtml"/>
        </rule>
    </navigation>
</page>
```

Comment: Actually, if you use asterisk, you will get redirection loop on the editUserPwd.xhtml page. Anyway, I've decided to handle this situation with Observer that check whether user's password is expired on JSF lifecycle phase.